# messagebox causes poor responsiveness windows phone 8

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When I run my app in store test kit (Automated test-Windows phone application analysis) **I get a red mark near responsiveness as app responsiveness is poor**, I am using a background thread to call a web service and display a messagebox with particular result from web service.
I have tried using separate thread and dispatcher for displaying the message box, still I get the same results in store kit.**I am sure that other parts of my code are not causing it, when I comment out messagebox.show(), the app passes responsiveness test.**
There is one more link I found relevant http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/dfd3bc28-6a90-4a77-92f7-c42982eafa40/app-poor-responsiveness-in-wp7?forum=wpdevelop it says this would not affect the certification process,Can some one please confirm this or provide more details of how do I go about making my app responsive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Message boxes are synchronous, when you display one then the UI thread stops processing the other elements of your interface. That why an automated testing tool will detect it as a lack of responsiveness, even though it's on purpose. Don't worry about it, it won't affect the certification process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ... I wanted to make sure of it before I submit it to store.. n I don understand y ppl downvote..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Indeed, I don't see anything wrong with your question

Comment: Short and clear answer. It's our first App to go to the Marketplace so we didn't know. Thanks!